# Is it allowed to answer a question with a (YouTube) video?

Tags: discussion, answers, hyperlinks

I really like to learn math by watching YouTube videos.
Especially those of the Khan Academy, here an [example](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus/sequences_series_approx_calc/maclaurin_taylor/v/euler-s-formula-and-euler-s-identity?v=mgNtPOgFje0) of a Khan Academy video.

I've been thinking of making a math video in Khan's style myself.
I don't know if I would be able to make a good video, but I would like to give it a try (some day). Is it allowed to answer a question with a (YouTube) video ?

Comment: An answer could consist of a link to a relevant resource. Depending on circumstances, some users may feel that that is not a good answer. For example the users with limited bandwidth might feel this way. This is not meant to discourage you, just to say that opinions may be divided.

Comment: You could try it out and see what people think. As far as I know, this would be the first time it's been done

Comment: @mixedmath: I seem to remember youtube links given out before for answers. But this would be to my knowledge the first time a YouTube video is specifically filmed to answer a question.

Comment: Just a side note. Typical math videos (including khan academy) are just not upto the mark compared to typical answers on mathse. Mathematical correctness is often sacrificed in such popular videos.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh What is a typical math video? Are the [Simons Institute](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCW1C2xOfXsIzPgjXyuhkw9g/videos) videos typical? What is the difference between answering a question by citing a recent preprint on arXiv and linking to the YouTube video of a recent talk?

Comment: Being able to add videos to answers would be a cool feature to add. Like how one can add images now. Looking to the future, say, 5, 10, 20 years from now, I can see this eventually becoming standard on QA sites.

Comment: I answered with a link to a YouTube video here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/94842/454

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As long as the answer is on topic, answers the question, is not offensive, and not spam, then most users won't have a problem with you posting a YouTube Link.
2. It is perhaps better, however (since the YouTube link URLs are usually rather cryptic, and I often hesitate to click on random links on the internet), to give a little bit more than a link: say that you are linking to a video you made yourself to demonstrate the answer, and perhaps a few quick words about the methods used (to solve the problem).
3. As usual, we have no control (besides some basic vote-fraud detection system) on how users will vote in response to your proposed answer. As Pavel [wrote](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7105/is-it-allowed-to-answer-a-question-with-a-youtube-video#comment26202_7105), users may have legitimate reasons to find a video response less useful.

Comment: What if the answer is on topic, answers the question, is not offensive, but **is** spam?

Comment: @PavelM: [Mission accomplished](http://xkcd.com/810/).

Comment: @PavelM Explain *how* an answer could be on topic, answer the question, not be offensive, AND be spam?? (I'm a little confused here...)  `:-)`

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest also posting a short/abbreviated (textual) answer.  If I came across an answer that was simply a YouTube video, I would skip by the answer rather than upvoting.  (This is not to say I wouldn't watch the video if I asked the question--rather, if I didn't ask the question, but just stumbled upon it.)

I tend not to watch random videos.  It takes longer for me to determine if a video is good/incredible (versus a total waste of my time) than to determine if a textual response is good.

That said: if there was a clear textual response that I liked, and it closed by saying, "I've explained this in [a more clear fashion]/[more detail]/[a graphical way]/[etc.] in this video (link)," I would probably follow the video link.

tl;dr: A video link by itself wouldn't attract my attention.  However, if accompanied by a short/barebones answer, I would be much more interested.